# Segfault caused in OpenTLD VarianceFilter

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am using the OpenTLD C++ implementation as a library - only including the [libopentld](https://github.com/gnebehay/OpenTLD/tree/82631ed299dbf8227d8c4b844e3227adcb165cb5/src/libopentld) folder. I've successfully compiled the main executable many times and it runs without a hitch. But using the library seems to have a weirdly specific bug.

I'm using opencv 3.0 for the default opentld and my own project.

Running with `-g -O0` and through `gdb` gives the following output:

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  calcVariance (off=0x7f3e060f45b0, this=0x15568a0) at libs/opentld/src/libopentld/tld/VarianceFilter.cpp:67
67      float mX  = (ii1[off[3]] - ii1[off[2]] - ii1[off[1]] + ii1[off[0]]) / (float) off[5]; //Sum of Area divided by area
(gdb) bt
#0  calcVariance (off=0x7f3e060f45b0, this=0x15568a0) at libs/opentld/src/libopentld/tld/VarianceFilter.cpp:67
#1  tld::VarianceFilter::filter (this=0x15568a0, i=23100) at libs/opentld/src/libopentld/tld/VarianceFilter.cpp:89
#2  0x00000000004141cd in tld::DetectorCascade::detect (this=0x1556780, img=...) at libs/opentld/src/libopentld/tld/DetectorCascade.cpp:317
#3  0x00000000004115bc in tld::TLD::initialLearning (this=0x15437c0) at libs/opentld/src/libopentld/tld/TLD.cpp:248
#4  0x0000000000411e0c in tld::TLD::selectObject (this=<optimized out>, img=..., bb=bb@entry=0x7ffcbe8caa70)
```

This occurs in the stack when I call `TLD::selectObject(img, roi)`.

I've isolated the array accesses, and it looks like `off[5]` is the culprit, but I'm not certain. It seems that they all access memory that isn't defined for them. In `IntegralImage` the width and height are never defined, but the data array is the size of `width*height` by convention. (and the array accesses that I'm logging seem to be outside of that range)

I don't know why this works for the normal executable but not calling from my own program. I've looked many times, stripped the normal one to just a few calls and it still works. Is it possible that it has something to do with using only Mat objects instead of IplImage?

Here's my code that calls opentld:

```
using namespace cv;
Target OpenTLD::findTarget(cv::Mat HSV, bool restart) {
  Target t;
  cvtColor(HSV, t.image, COLOR_HSV2RGB);
  Mat BGR;
  cvtColor(t.image, BGR, COLOR_RGB2BGR);
  Mat grey(HSV.size(), CV_8UC1);
  int ch[] = {2, 0};
  mixChannels(&HSV, 1, &grey, 1, ch, 1);

  if (restart) {
    started = true;
    Rect roi = selectedROI();
    tld->detectorCascade->imgWidth = HSV.cols;
    tld->detectorCascade->imgHeight = HSV.rows;
    tld->detectorCascade->imgWidthStep = HSV.step;
    tld->processImage(BGR);
    tld->selectObject(grey, &roi);
  } else if (started) {
    t.roi = ROI(*tld->currBB);
    tld->processImage(BGR);
  }

  return t;
}
```

I've verified that the images and ROIs are valid values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to `HSV.step` giving wrong values. I used the width value, and it works perfectly fine.